# Add project to source control hangs VS 2013

Tags: windows, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Using VS 2013 Premium I get ~10 minute hang every time I try to add a new project into our TFS server using the File->Source Control->Add Selected Project(s) to Source Control command. This hang results in the standard Windows "not responding" behavior but WILL complete if left to run out the course of its 10 minute duration. Task mgr shows it using ~4% CPU and a steady 4Mbps of network activity, meaning it's likely communicating with TFS. I've ruled out a bad network connection and for what it's worth, other TFS <---> Visual Studio interactions perform perfectly fine.

Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: I have the same setup but have not seen this yet.

Comment: I had something similar on loading a project.  Try deleting the v12.suo file and try it again.

Comment: @MikeDouglasDev Tried deleting the v12.suo, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS could be taking a long time to process the request, meaning that something may be configured incorrectly or in a sub-optimal way with your environment.

Try running the [TFS Best Practice Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vstudio/cc137713) that comes with TFS Power Tools on your TFS server and see if anything sticks out, especially with regards to your TfsService account.  I've seen people have performance issues in the past executing certain functions when a Windows Group Policy was preventing TFS from having the right access privileges it wanted on the machine.  Oddly enough the jobs would run successfully but take an inordinate amount of time.

For deep-level diagnostics you could also run the [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on both your client and server to see what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Marking this as answer because it's great advice. Even though I didn't use it to figure this particular issue out, I could have. Turned out to be proxy settings. We have a local TFS server that is a proxy for the main remote TFS server. Needed to use the proxy to get performance acceptable. Not sure why this never was an issue ion the past, but we've recently upgraded TFS/VS to 2013, so there's that.